# Spotify API throws TypeError in Player view

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to add the Player view to my app, so I'll get the cover art and the play/pause buttons. However, when I try to click the play button, the API throws an TypeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   Album.get
>   Object.defineProperties.playing.set
>   Player.play.context

The faulting code seems to be in models.js, on line: 641:

```
Album.prototype.get = function(index) {  
    if (index >= this.data.tracks.length) {  
        throw new RangeError("Index out of range");  
    }  
    return new Track(this.data.tracks[index]);  
};
```

My code looks like this:

```
var p = new views.Player(); 
p.context = track.album; 
document.getElementById('album-element').appendChild ( p.node );
```

Is this a bug in the spotify API, or some undocumented event?

Answer (score 0):

The tracks property from track.album does not get populated. I don't know if this is intended or not.

A solution would be if you want to create a player view only based on a track, get the album uri in that track object and create an album object based on it and then pass it to the context of the view.

```
models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:5XZ72GmBONwRGYltKlg1jv', function(track) {
    models.Album.fromURI(track.album.uri, function(album) {
        var p = new views.Player(); 
        p.context = album; 
        document.getElementById('album-element').appendChild ( p.node );
    });
});
```